# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on a high-resolution display laptop

Tags: 12.04, installation, themes

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 with compiz on a 17" laptop with 1920x1080 display. After the installation the fonts are too small. Even if I change the fonts' size the Close/Minimize/Mazimize icons remain tiny, Is tehre any appropriate theme for high-resolution displays? How can I install it?